# Do an INSERT query only if two values are not in a row

Tags: php, insert

Hi guys i have this simple script

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO giorni (a1, a2, a3, a4, giorno, data, punto) VALUES ('$a1', '$a2', '$a3', '$a4', '$date', '$inglese', '$punto' )";
```

I don't know how to prevent to insert data in my table if values from $date and $punto are present in the same row yet.

do I have to do another query or is it possible to change it ?
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: did you know you can use a decisional statement in php?

Comment: What database are you using? You mean you don't want multiple records with the same `giorno` & `punto` values?

Comment: You can put a UNIQUE constraint on the database table, which would cause an SQL error to be triggered if you attempt to insert non-unique values.

Comment: By the way, your SQL query is potentially open to SQL injection attacks (DEFINITELY if you've not sanitised your input, and even if you have it still may be vulnerable).  You should never use inserted variables or string concatenation to create parameterised queries, use the prepared query features of mysqli or PDO instead.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Yuan Tee, i don't want to use insert if my input from form contains BOTH variables in one row. If there is only one, it's ok. Gordon i use it on a local pc with no connection, only a simple interface.. thanks for advice by the way!! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if($date && $punto) {
   echo "sorry invalid insert";
} else {
   //run query
}
```

Comment: All this does is print the error message if $date and $punto are both set to values that don't evaluate to boolean false

Comment: you are right though he wanted to check if the variables were there before the insert not the values from the db... read question wrong